# How to print a matplotlib figure without saving it first?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.plot(x) # plot some data
    plt.savefig('output.ps') # I can also save from the menu
    plt.show()
```

one can save a matplotlib figure. How can one directly print a figure on a color printer without saving it first? What that means is that, is there a plt.printfig() ?

Comment: I don't think matplotlib has such functionality.